# How do popular web applications (e.g. Facebook, Google) keep sessions alive so long without risking security?

Tags: facebook, security, http, session

I'm writing my own authentication code and I've been reading a lot about possible attacks. One attack vector is that an attacker hijacks the session and uses this information to perform malicious actions as an authenticated user. I've read that the work-around to this is to expire the session frequently or at least renew the session periodically.

This got me thinking, I can't remember the last time I signed into Facebook. I stay signed in from many devices, some of which I don't use every day (e.g. work laptop). I'm wondering, how do they have such long-lived sessions without risking session hijacking?

Comment: They don’t necessarily keep the session itself (in the common meaning of a web session, that associates server-side data with a client by a session id) alive for an extended period of time; but they store a token in a cookie that can be used to _authenticate_ the user on their next visit to the site, so that a _new_ session can be started then.

Comment: Try on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CBroe Authenticity token vs. session information is more of a implementation detail. The fact that a long-lived authenticity token is stored in a cookie would still represent some security risk, but I guess making access to the cookie difficult is the default security mechanism.

Comment: Well they probably include stuff such as a browser/device fingerprint, to make it harder to get a stolen cookie to work from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS. Many session hijacking attacks work by sniffing cookies "in flight". Using HTTPS greatly raises the effort required to do this successfully.